# Connecting two binary objects in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary matrix containing several binary objects and I want to bridge between them. Actually I have the following picture:

[image: startingpoint]

And the result has to be like this:

[image: result]

Is there any function or a shortcut way, other than loops, for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Morphological operations are suitable but i would suggest line structuring element as your arrangement is horizontal and you do not want overlaps between lines:

```
 clear
 clc
 close all

 BW = im2bw(imread('Silhouette.png'));
 BW = imclearborder(BW);


 se = strel('line',10,0); 
 dilateddBW = imdilate(BW,se);       
 img= imerode(BW,se);

 figure;
 imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a morphological close for this purpose

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imclose.html

Try using a square structuring element of various sizes until you get what you expect.